# What are some of the internal details of the processing of a lazily evaluated expression in a Scala stream?

Tags: scala, stream

This is less of a how-to question than a "what is going on behind the scenes?" question.  I have been trying to get a better understanding of what is going on under the hood in Scala when the expression "fib.tail.tail.tail" is evaluated in the context of the following function definition:

```
   lazy val fib:Stream[Long]=
      Stream.cons(1, 
       Stream.cons(2, fib.zip(fib.tail).
             map(x=>x._1+x._2)))
```

I think my mental picture is correct, but I'd really appreciate it if someone with deeper Scala experience can critique it and let me know what's missing, or incorrect.  Here is diagram which illustrates my "mental model":[image: diagram of what happens in evaluation of lazily evaluated tail part of a Scala Stream]

Thank you in advance for your guidance !